# SQL help needed to shorten the query to iterate through columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table of about 200 columns having primary key as the ID and almost 180 of them are y/n fed. But i have to calculate one column “percentage” through calculating total “y” present from overall y/n columns for each ID in the table.

Any help will be appreciated.

I’m bound to use  access and I’m searching for a short query to do it in SQL. I can use column names to write the query but that will take lots of time.

Comment: If the table was UNPIVOTED first then you'd only have to search a single column. Unfortunately to UNPIVOT in ms access you must write each one separately and UNION ALL for all 180 columns so that would likely take just as long to do.

Comment: There is no short query for this. You can use VBA to build the SQL, by looping the tabledef fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *VBA* and *DAO* to loop the table:

```vb
Public Function CheckPercent()

    Const Sql           As String = "Select * From YourTable"
    
    Dim Records         As DAO.Recordset
    Dim Field           As DAO.Field
    
    Dim Total           As Integer
    Dim Selected        As Integer
    
    Set Records = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Sql)
    While Not Records.EOF
        ' Calculate.
        Total = 0
        Selected = 0
        For Each Field In Records.Fields
            If Field.Type = dbBoolean Then
                Total = Total + 1
                Selected = Selected + Abs(Field.Value)
            End If
        Next

        ' Print result.
        Debug.Print "Id " & Records(0).Value, "Total " & Total, "Selected " & Selected, Format(Selected / Total, "Percent")

        ' Save the percentage for this record in field PercentSelected 
        ' having the data type Currency.
        Records.Edit
        Records!PercentSelected.Value = Selected / Total
        Records.Update

        ' Move on.
        Records.MoveNext
    Wend
    Records.Close
    
End Function
```

Output example:

```
Id 1002       Total 8       Selected 5    62,50%
Id 1003       Total 8       Selected 6    75,00%
```

Comment: Hi, im quite new to vba. Can you help me here how to put this percentage into a whole new column

Comment: Yes. See extended answer, please.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me a lot with my issue.